# How to keep Azure Point-To-Site VPN secure?

Tags: networking, vpn, azure

Following these [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn133792.aspx) I was able to successfully create and connect to a Windows Azure VPN.

However, it appears that there are no ACLs on the VPN and all security is controlled via certificates.   How do we handle the scenario where we need to "revoke" a client certificate (ie., a developer who has a cert leaves the company) ?

Is it possible to revoke a certificate with Azure VPN and Point-To-Site?  If not, how do I secure a Point-To-Site VPN?

Answer (score 0):

The security is based on potentially a sets of certificates (typically self-signed) - each set has a 'root certificate' which is deployed to Azure and client certificates that are linked to it. 
If you remove a particular 'root certificate' from the network configuration on Azure you remove access to all client certificates that are linked to it.

Unfortunately you cannot control a specific client (not without create a set for each client, which, in most cases, is unsustainable) and so if you do need to remove a specific client you are likely to have to create a new set, excluding the client you wish to remove and re-distribute the set to all other clients.

Comment: Does that mean in practice: If I distribute the downloadable VPN configuration from Azure and use it to setup multiple cllients, then each client will generate its own certificate, but as all clients I setup using the same package share a root cert, I can only either disable all or none of them?